# How do I Validate or check if prompt value is in object

Tags: javascript, validation, object

When category is not in object the code alerts('not found'),but alerts('found') when item is not in the object.

```js
let item_prices = {
  noodles:{ 'big': 14, 'small': 15 },
  pen: { 'big': 17, 'small': 14 }  
};

let category = prompt('enter category');
let item = prompt('enter item name');

if (!(category in item_prices) || (item in item_prices)) {
  alert('not found')
} else {
  alert('found')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Item_prices` object is lack of `:` in object and properties <s>should not be a string</s> (Maybe I misspelled the phrase - it's better to use it without "string" from my point of view, [we see more often that approach](https://javascript.info/object) and "string" property is strongly assigned with JSON files)

```
let item_prices = {
  noodles: { big: 14, small: 15 },
  pen: { big: 17, small: 14 },
};
```

The rest of the logic works for me

---

btw. you forgot probably a little bit of logic there -> `!(category in item_prices) || item in item_prices`

> **If category isn't in obj** or **item is in obj** show "not found"

so input data

```
category: noodles
item: medium
```

will show me `found` - but it's not there :)

Comment: Why properties shouldn't be strings? 
Also, if is just a type, there's no need to answer, just flag the question and point out in the comments

Comment: @CalvinNunes true, but here he has logic issues too - I've edited my answer so I could point this too

Comment: @calvin Nunes what is I want to space out the properties like {noodles:{small size:15}} something like this

Comment: @Kelvinlee hmm only in this situation ["multiword property name must be quoted"](https://javascript.info/object)

Comment: and of course, the "getting into this" will be like `noodles["small size"]`